# Analysing nasal glides

Tags: phonology

For my phonology homework, we're given the nasals [n] [m] [η] and nasalized glides [w] and [j]. From the data, I've found that [n] and [m] are phonemes and [η] is an allophone of /n/. What I can't figure out is where the nasal glides fit in. They appear w̃ and ȷ̃.

---

The exact question is this:

> [image: fron the pdf with the question]
>
> [source](http://udel.edu/~heinz/classes/2013/4-603/materials/readings/Hayes2008-03.pdf) (section 3 on page 67)

Comment: Look at the data.  What phonetic contexts do w̃ and ȷ̃ appear in?  They only appear before w and j, right?  What does that tell you?

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, the nasalized glides w̃ and ȷ̃ are cases where ん or N (the Japanese syllable-final moraic nasal sound/uvular nasal) comes before /w/ and /j/ approximants, or in other words, the w or y-sounds. Observe these: (koNya with ȷ̃) こ**ん**や, (yaNwari with w̃) や**ん**わり, (kaNyo with ȷ̃)　か**ん**よ.

In general, where the ん or N comes before /j/ and /w/, the N nasalizes stuff. This answer's pretty simple though. Please add on or correct as needed!